# wpf combobox not updating properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I am new to wpf and fighting with this issue for several days. I have a combobox which has dataview as itemssource. It displays the values correctly but selecteditem is always null when i re-run the application.

ChargeCodeValidValues objects that combobox is bound to:

```
public class ChargeCodeValidValues
{
    #region Properties

    public DataTable ChargeCodesValidValuesTable { get; set; }
    public DataView dvChargeCodeValidValues { get; set; }       

    #endregion
    #region Constructor

    public ChargeCodeValidValues()
    {
        LoadChargeCodesValidValues();
    }

    public void LoadChargeCodesValidValues()
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        DataTable dataTable = db.ExecuteQuery("upGet_ChargeCodesValidValues", "ChargeCodesValidValues", "ID");

        this.ChargeCodesValidValuesTable = dataTable;
        this.dvChargeCodeValidValues = ChargeCodesValidValuesTable.DefaultView;
    }
```

XAML:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="combodescriptionTemplate">
      <ComboBox Name="cboCombo"
                Loaded="cboCombo_Loaded">
           <ComboBox.DataContext>
                <Objects:ChargeCodeValidValues/>
           </ComboBox.DataContext>
      </ComboBox>
 </DataTemplate>  

 <local:TotalCellTemplateSelector x:Key="totalcellTemplateSelector" 
           combodescriptionTemplate="{StaticResource combodescriptionTemplate}"/>
```

gridview column :

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Description" FieldName="Description" Width="Auto" MinWidth="132" AllowMoving="False" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource totalcellTemplateSelector}" /> -->
```

this column is textbox by default. It changes to combobox based on values from other column

code:

```
 private void cboCombo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
      DataTable dtChargeCodeValidValues = oChargeCodesValidvalues.ChargeCodesValidValuesTable.Copy();
      DataView dvCurrentCodeValues = dtChargeCodeValidValues.Copy().DefaultView;
      cmb.ItemsSource = dvCurrentCodeValues;
      cmb.DisplayMemberPath = "Description";
      cmb.SelectedValuePath = "Description";
      cmb.SelectedValue = "Description";
 }
```

Comment: are you familiar with `ObservableCollection and DataBinding` that way http://wpflog.blogspot.com/2009/04/very-simple-observablecollection.html

Comment: Not that much familiar. But i do not think that example can be applied on my situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic that will persist a selection in a `ComboBox` across different invocations of your application; you'll have to write the code yourself. For example:

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="comboBox"
    SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
    Loaded="OnComboBoxLoaded"
    >
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <system:String>One</system:String>
        <system:String>Two</system:String>
        <system:String>Three</system:String>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

...with the following code-behind:

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
    using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.CreateFile("selectedIndex"))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(index.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

private void OnComboBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = GetPreviousIndex();
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = index;
    comboBox.Text = comboBox.Items[index] as string;
}

private int GetPreviousIndex()
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile("selectedIndex", FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                try
                {
                    return int.Parse(reader.ReadString());
                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that setting the `SelectedIndex` is insufficient; you have to set the `Text` property as well, or you won't see the selection without opening the `ComboBox`.

There are many ways of persisting the selection, of course; here I just cobbled something together quickly (and somewhat dirtily).

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. But the provided logic did not work and I need to populate combobox values from database

Comment: I assure you that the code does work; I've tested it. I realize that you need to populate the `ComboBox` from a DB -- the appropriate place to set the selection to its saved value would be after that. I'm a bit curious about the last three lines of your `cboCombo_Loaded` method -- what does it mean that all three properties are set to "Description"?
And when you exit the program or change a selection, do you make a record of it anywhere?

Comment: I want to save the combobox text in the form of string.I am doing this because this column is text by default.I have the selectionchanged event and it works fine while i select and save. When i re-run application, selected item/text is null in combobox but populates the value

Comment: Using `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedIndex` is fine. Do you set the `ComboBox.Text` property as well?

Comment: I have used combobbox.text property as well but it did not make any difference.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas, without actually debugging your code. Good luck going forward with this!